# TestNG: How to find @Test without parameter 'priority'?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea, testng

I've got some old tests in TestNG. Some of them was written without priority, and some others was set the same number of priority.

e.g.:

```
@Test(description = "Adding invoice")    
...
@Test(description = "Adding document", priority = 18421)
...
@Test(description = "Recognizing document", priority = 18421)
```

1. How to quickly find @Test without parameter 'priority'?
2. How to quickly find @Test with the same number of 'priority'?

Best way will be with some script or tool ... of course I can seart manually, but this is waste of time :)

Comment: You can try SSR: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/structural-search-and-replace.html.

Comment: Thanks Crazycoder.
I find all places ended with 4 digits using Regex [0-9]{4}"\)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find all places begined with annotation @Test and ended with quote mark (priority are ended with digits) using Regex `@Test\(.*"\)`